# Azure Terraform An invalid parameter NetworkMappingName was passed.","possibleCauses":"Parameter value is not correct for this action."

Tags: azure, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to mapping network for site recovery but facing following issue.

```
Error: Error checking for presence of existing site recovery network mapping recovery-network-mapping (vault recovery-vault-360f): siterecovery.ReplicationNetworkMappingsClient#Get: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="BadRequest" Message="An invalid parameter NetworkMappingName was passed." Details=[{"activityId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","clientRequestId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","code":"InvalidParameter","message":"An invalid parameter NetworkMappingName was passed.","possibleCauses":"Parameter value is not correct for this action.","recommendedAction":"Correct the parameter value and retry the last action. If the issue persists, contact Support."}]

  on modules/site_recovery/main.tf line 78, in resource "azurerm_site_recovery_network_mapping" "mapping":
  78: resource "azurerm_site_recovery_network_mapping" "mapping" {
```

main.tf file:

```
    #Create Virtual Network in Primary Resource Group
        resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "primary" {
          name                = var.virtual_network
          resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
          location            = var.location
          address_space       = var.address_space
          depends_on          = [var.resource_group_name]
          tags = {
                environment = "Test"
            }
        }

        #Create Subnet in Virtual Network
        resource "azurerm_subnet" "primary1" {
          name                 = var.subnet1
          virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.primary.name
          resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
          address_prefix       = var.address_prefix1
        }
        output "vnet_id1" {
        value = "${azurerm_virtual_network.primary.id}"
        }
```

Site recovery module root main.tf file:
main.tf file:

```
        module "site_recovery" {
        -----------
        -----------
        network_mapping       = "recovery-network-mapping"
        vnet_id1              = "${module.network.vnet_id1}"
        -----------
        -----------
        }
```

Site recovery module:

```
resource "azurerm_site_recovery_network_mapping" "mapping" {
        name                        = var.network_mapping
        resource_group_name         = var.sec_resource_group
        recovery_vault_name         = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.vault.name
        source_recovery_fabric_name = var.primary_fabric
        target_recovery_fabric_name = var.seconday_fabric
        source_network_id           = var.vnet_id1
        target_network_id           = azurerm_virtual_network.secondary.id
        depends_on                  = [var.vnet_id1, azurerm_virtual_network.secondary]
        }
```

site_recovery variable.tf:

```
           variable "vnet_id1" {
               description = "The name of Primary VNET"
               }
           variable "network_mapping" {
           description = "The name of Recovery Protection network_mapping"
                }
```

I am getting mapping name parameters Invalid.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug. I also face the same issue when tried it with [terraform document](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/site_recovery_network_mapping.html). Also, there is a similar [open issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/6026) on GitHub.

Comment: How to overcome, this issue, as can not site recovery without this ?

Comment: I have not got a solution to it yet. If I got it resolved, I will reply back.